# Kotlin Type Mismatch : Required Long found Unit

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a pojo class in java as below

```
public class Pojo{
     @SerializedName("notificationTime")
     private long notificationTime;

     public long getNotificationTime(){
          return notificationTime;
    }
 }
```

Now i am trying this notificationTime in kotlin as below

```
var notifTime:Long = Pojo.notificationTime
```

It is showing compiltime error as mentioned . Please help. I am new to kotlin.

Comment: Do you instantiate your Pojo?

Comment: as you are "new to Kotlin", please have a look at: [Kotlin reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/)... the same link will also lead you to some [tutorials](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an instance, `Pojo.notificationTime` tries to call a static method. Which is not what your code exposes.

So init your object, then gets its `notificationTime`:

```
val pojo = Pojo()
val notifTime = pojo.notificationTime // actually calls `getNotificationTime()` as an implicit getter
```